# Open GL Translation on Y axis using Java or C#

Tags: java, c#, opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am new to OpenGL and I have a Triangle that gets created to my surfaceView which in turns shows on my screen. I have been able to add Rotation to make my Triangle rotate however that is not what I need. I have been looking around a lot into OpenGL and have read into Transformation and then into Translation which I believe to be correct for adding vertical movement to my Triangle, however with my current understanding I have been unable to implement this.

**Example:**

Triangle is created at the top of the screen and moves down the Y axis towards the bottom of the screen.

This translation is on an angle however it shows what I mean, I would just like to move in y-Axis.

[image]

**I have a Render as follows:**

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    //Project Matrix
    private float mMatrix[] = new float[16];
    private Triangle mTriangle;

    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mModelMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mTempMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];

    // Called once to set up the view's opengl es environment
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config){

    //Set the background frame color
    GLES30.glClearColor(208.0f,208.0f,208.0f,1.0f);

    mTriangle= new Triangle();
}

// Called for each redraw of the view
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl){
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Redraw background color
    GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Apply transformation, start with translation
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0); // initialize to identity matrix
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, -0.5f, 0, 0); // translation to the left
    // Create a rotation transformation for the triangle
    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % 4000L;
    float mAngle = 0.090f * ((int) time);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

    Matrix.orthoM(mMatrix, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

    // Combine Rotation and Translation matrices
    mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    // Combine the model matrix with the projection and camera view
    mTempMatrix = mMVPMatrix.clone();
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);

    mTriangle.draw(mMatrix);

}

// Called if the geometry of the view changes (example is when the screen orientation changes from landscape to portrait
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height){
    // Called if the geometry of the viewport changes
    GLES30.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    // create a vertex shader type (GLES30.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES30.glCreateShader(type);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES30.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES30.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
}
```

**I have a triangle as follows:**

```
public class Triangle {

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
    // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
    // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
    "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
     "void main() {" +
     // the matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position
     // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
     // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
     "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
     "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
      "precision mediump float;" +
      "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
      "void main() {" +
      "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
      "}";

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
    static float triangleCoords[] = {
    // in counterclockwise order:
    0.0f,  0.622008459f, 0.0f,   // top
    -0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
    0.5f, -0.311004243f, 0.0f    // bottom right
};

private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex
float color[] = { 0.63671875f, 0.76953125f, 0.22265625f, 0.0f };

/**
 * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
 */
public Triangle() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
    triangleCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
    int vertexShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
      GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = MyGLRenderer.loadShader(
      GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);

    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

}

/**
 * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
 *
 * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
 * this shape.
 */
public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
    // Add program to OpenGL environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
      mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
      GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
      vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // Apply the projection and view transformation
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}

}
```

**I have a Surface View as follows:**

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);

    //Create an OpenGl 3.0 context
    setEGLContextClientVersion(3);

    mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();

    //Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
}

}
```

I am looking for a bare bones example/answer/URL that can accomplish moving a drawn Triangle on the y axis (I am assuming using Translation).

I have read and tried to implement the following links (some way above my current understanding).

1. http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/rotation.html
2. http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html
3. https://open.gl/transformations
4. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2111395&seqNum=3
5. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/

As well as a few others however these seem to be the best sources I have found.

Comment: Yes, it would be a translation. It is quite simple, all you would need to do is to modify `mvpMatrix ` in the `draw()` method of `Triangle`. Translate the matrix on the Y axis by the y-position of the triangle using whatever library you are using (I am not sure, but for example, `Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, trianglePos.y, 0, 0, 0);`) and give the newly modified matrix to `glUniformMatrix4fv()`. Of course, to make it move, you have to increment the triangle's y-position each frame.

Comment: And, if you aren't already, you need to keep track of the triangle's position!

Comment: Any chance you could answer the question with an example given the code provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be a translation. It is quite simple, all you would need to do is to modify `mvpMatrix` in the `draw()` method of `Triangle`.

It is important to keep track of the triangle's position to make it move, however. You would add private member to the class resembling this:

```
private Point mPosition;
```

Keep in mind, the `Point` in that code is a simple point/vector class I am assuming you have since I am pretty sure this is on android? Check out [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html).

Then, you would need to increment the y-position of the triangle each frame. You could do this in `draw()`, but I would add another method for movement.

```
mPosition.y += 0.01;
```

Note: *I see you have an MVP matrix as an argument to `draw`. Right now, since this is 2D and orthogonic, it is not that important, but think about moving your rotation from the `onDrawFrame()` function into the `Triangle.draw()`, since the M stands for Model which would normally be per model/triangle. Normally, you would only pass the VP (view and projection) to the `Triangle.draw()` method. Check [this](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/) out.*

Finally, you would translate the mvp matrix in the `Triangle.draw()` method by the triangle's position. So, before passing the matrix to the shader (before `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);`), translate it:

```
Matrix.translateM(mvpMatrix, mPosition.x, mPosition.y);
// Or whatever translate method you have, I am not sure
```